# Redis out-of-memory when maxmemory-policy set

Tags: .net, hangfire

I have Redis 6.2.1 running in container (OpenShift) with 2 GB ram. Redis has configuration:

- `maxmemory-policy`: `volatile-ttl`
- `maxmemory-samples`: `5`
- `maxmemory`: `1073741824` (1GB)

But when there is a peek I sometimes get errors: `Transaction was discarded to prevent inconsistency: one or more of active distributed locks were abandoned. Are you hitting Redis memory limits?`.

Why is that? Most records in Redis has TTL set so there is plenty records to discard. I would expect this exception only if there are no other records with TTL set which is definitely not the case here.

Why am I getting this exception? What am I missing?

Comment: That is not a redis error message.

Comment: Check this article since it seems some threading or cpu  issue which is causing this issue https://www.programmersought.com/article/58124498890/

Comment: This error is thrown by Hangfire.Pro.Redis package. No ideas why, but it's not Redis on its own.